# CSS transition effect is "lagging"

Tags: css

I have:

```css
#t {
  background: bisque;
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transition:0.5s;
}
#t:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="t"></div>
```

As you can see when I hover - `transition` effect is starting to "lag", probably because I add `border-bottom` as a hover effect which is not appropriate (?), but not sure.

How could I avoid such "lagging" and add `transition: 0.5s;` for `border-bottom` appearance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because border sizes can only be defined and "stepped through" in integer values, so you cannot have subpixel borders, which causes the jerky effect. A solution will simply to render a pseudo-element with the 3px height, but transform it such that it starts with `scaleY(0)`, and on hover expand it to its full height using `scaleY(1)`.

To give the appearance that the scaling starts from the top edge of the pseudo-element, you will also need to use `transform-origin: top center`.

See proof-of-concept:

```css
#t {
  background: bisque;
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#t::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: grey;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#t:hover::before {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="t"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also simulate the border bottom with box-shadow.

```css
#t {
    display: block;
    background: bisque;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  }  

  #t:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 grey;
  }
```

```html
<div id="t"></div>
```

Thanks to CSS-Tricks about [Animating Border](https://css-tricks.com/animating-border/#method-5-fake-it-with-box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

You can let the border in transparent color and on hover just change it to a visible color, that should go more smooth